# Are spring @Autowired fields automatically private?

Tags: java, spring

what is the difference between those 2 examples :

```
public class A{
@Autowired 
private MyField myField;
}
```

and

```
  public class A{
    @Autowired 
    MyField myField;
    }
```

Comment: .setParameter("num", 1).  What is the data type of etapesnum?

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(int)` (because you can't cast an `Integer` to a `String`).

Comment: @AymanRbati -- I think it's no good idea to **completely change** the title and the content of your question when there alread exist comments and answers. I suggest to delete this question and repost it anew.

Comment: i can't do i got kind of banned so help if u can help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
.setParameter("num", 1).getResultList();
```

try:

```
 .setParameter("num", "1").getResultList();
```

Convert the int to a string and call setParameter, or better use setInteger().

I'm a little surprised setParaneter() doesn't handle the conversion.  Oh the mysteries of strongly typed languages!